# How to print stream multiple times?

Tags: bash, shell, sh, xargs

```
cat ciao.py | tee >(xargs echo) | xargs echo
```

and the output is:

```
print(ciaoo) print(ciaoo)
```

I'd like to print the stream two times using only one starting stream. How can I do that?
echo and printf seems not work. Is there another way to do it without xargs? A cleaner way?

Also, how can I print them in new line like these?

```
print(ciaoo)
print(ciaoo)
```

EDIT:
I know I can do `sed 's/.*/&\n&/' ciao.py` but instead I want to do that via pipe stream, maybe could be useful in certain scenarios.

Also, if I do `cat ciao.py | sed 's/.*/&\n&/'` it would work, but I want to do this in two separated times, simulating the case where I want to print it and then pass that to further commands.

**FIXED**: look here: [Why doesn't this sed command put a newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71338070/why-doesnt-this-sed-command-put-a-newline)

Comment: If the file has multiple lines, do you want to print each line twice (i.e. `line 1`, `line 1`, line 2`, `line 2`,...), or all lines and then all lines again (i.e. `line 1`, `line 2`,... `line 1`, `line 2`,...)?

Comment: the secondd one

Comment: How about `cat ciao.py | tee >(cat)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do so using `sed`

```
$ sed 's/.*/&\n&/' ciao.py
print(ciaoo)
print(ciaoo)
```

Comment: how to do that on a pipe, instead of giving it directly the file as input? If I put your code after the pipe, it shows in the same line, just like in my post :(

Comment: @Allexj  `cat ciao.py | sed 's/.*/&\n&/'`

Comment: yeah you are right, but I want to do this in two separated times, simulating the case where I want to print it and then pass that to further commands. Why doesn't `cat ciao.py | sed 's/.*/&\n/'  |tee >(xargs echo) | xargs echo` work?

Answer (score 0):

In order to print the stream twice, you need to save a copy somewhere temporarily, then print the copy when the first pass is finished. Something like this:

```
produceStream | { tempfile=$(mktemp); tee "$tempfile"; cat "$tempfile"; rm "$tempfile"; }
```