# Why doesn't this sed command put a newline

Tags: bash, sed, pipe, xargs, tee

I have a file, ciao.py thas has only one line in it: `print("ciao")`

I want to do this: I want to do that via pipe stream, and als, if I do `cat ciao.py | sed 's/.*/&\n&/'` it would work, but I want to do this in two separated parts, simulating the case where I want to print it and then pass that to further commands.

If I do this:

`cat ciao.py | sed 's/.*/&\n/'  |tee >(xargs echo) | xargs echo`

it does not work. It prints `print("ciao") print("ciao")` in the same line. I don't understand why, since I am putting \n with sed.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Run the line as bash?

Comment: `printf 'foo\nbar\n' | xargs` prints one line.  But `printf 'foo\nbar\n' | xargs -L1` prints 2 lines. This is simply because xargs groups the arguments into a single echo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd guess `print cia` is appearing twice on the same line because `xargs` is calling `echo` with multiple strings since `xargs` calls the command you provide it with groups of input lines at a time by default.

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
$ cat ciao.py | sed 's/.*/&\n/'  |tee >(xargs -n 1 echo) | xargs -n 1 echo
print(ciao)
print(ciao)
```

or:

```
$ cat ciao.py | sed 's/.*/&\n/'  |tee >(cat) | xargs -n 1 echo
print(ciao)
print(ciao)
```

There are, of course, better ways to get that output from that input, e.g.:

```
$ sed 'p' ciao.py
print("ciao")
print("ciao")
```